# IClearCase, IClearTool usage in C#, How do I manage memory allocated

Tags: c#, memory-management, clearcase

On timer tick I am allocating new ClearCase ApplicationClass object, Is following code okay?
Or Do I need to release memory, If yes, How? I am using ClearCase Interop of ccauto.dll, I believe ccauto.dll is unmanaged code, I am confused, am I supposed to release the memory or not?

Please advise.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            IClearCase ccNew = new ApplicationClass();
            CCVOB vob = ccNew.get_VOB(ClearCaseVOB);
            ccNew = null;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

2 comments:

- according to ["About CAL3" article](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123249#getting):

> **Once you "GET" a ClearCase.Application object programmatically, do you need to keep getting the object in CAL?**
>   Once the `ClearCase.Application` object is obtained, it can be used to get other objects
>   without having to create them again.
>   CAL ensures as best it can that CAL objects stay synchronized with the underlying ClearCase data, refreshing as necessary when invoking properties and methods.
>   However, the CAL objects can become invalid if someone deletes the underlying ClearCase data while a reference is still held by the CAL object.

Meaning: you could set a `CCVOB` instance once and for all (unless you think the Vob will disappear... which should be a very rare event!)

- In C#, placing code in a using **block** ensures that the objects are disposed (though not necessarily collected) as soon as control leaves the block.

I am not sure if `CCVOB` implements `Disposable`, but if it does, setting it to null explicitly would prevent it to be properly disposed.
So I would not recommend `ccNew = null;`